# Creating resources in a new sub-account of my organization is giving SubscriptionRequiredException and OptInRequired errors

Tags: terraform

I am programmatically creating accounts in my overall AWS organization then attempting to create resources (sns topics, sqs queues, lambdas, etc) for those accounts via terraform, using an IAM user's credentials that I also programmatically create for those accounts ahead of time.

The account and IAM creation works fine (I can see the account in the console), but when I attempt to run `terraform apply` I get either `SubscriptionRequiredException` or `OptInRequired` `The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service` errors.  The other posts I've found on this topic were either unanswered or seemed to refer to individual accounts rather than sub-accounts of an organization, so they don't really seem relevant, but I apologize if I am missing a post that covers this somewhere.

I have checked that:

- I have consolidated billing enabled for my org
- One of my accounts is the management account
- My monthly bill does go to the management accounts credit card for all expenses in the org (including sub-accounts I've set up manually in the past)

On one of the other posts, I saw someone say they created a web login and logged in for the first time before these errors went away, so it's possible that's something I need to do, but I was really hoping to have the account creation and resource creation 100% automated.

Does anyone know why I am getting these errors even though my org appears to be set up correctly?  Can I opt-in programmatically from my programmatically-created accounts somehow?

Comment: This is a customer service-related question that should be taken up on the vendor's site with their support staff.